# How to apply jquery function to each instance

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to apply the .each method, so that each "response-text-area" on this page is targeted separately (I have multiple form submits on one page, and I want the submit buttons to be disabled on each one, until you enter text in its corresponding text area).  But I'm not sure where to drop it.  Can I chain methods?

(this is all in a document.ready)

```
$('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('.response-text-area').each.keyup(function() {
    if ($('.response-text-area').val() == "") {
        $('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the `.each` (whos syntax is incorrect anyway). The event will be bound to each control that has the class `response-text-area`.

```
$('.response-text-area').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        // I'd need to see your markup to provide code here. 
        // You need to find the correct submit button in relationship 
        // to the current item. Something similar to this:
        $(this).parent().find('.submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().find('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the each as this should work as well

```
$('.response-text-area').bind("keyup", function(){
    if($('.response-text-area').val() == ""){
         $('.submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else{
        $('.submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.response-text-area').keyup( function() {
    $( ".submit", this.form ).prop( "disabled", !this.value );
});
```